# c# Idle Game; Adding money issue

Tags: c#

I am currently working on a c# only (no Unity) Idle Game (A.K.A clicker game) where the user collects money by clicking a button and leveling up a gold mine, here is the code;

```
namespace Business_Tycoon
{
public partial class Form1 : Form
{       
    public decimal level;
    public decimal money;
    public decimal revenue;
    public decimal multiplier;
    public decimal price;
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        start();
    }
    void start()
    {
        money = 10;          
    }

    void update()
    {
        money = money + revenue;
    }


    void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        price = ((price/100) * 150m);
        level = (level + 1);
        multiplier = 1.10m;                
        money = (money - price);
        revenue = (level * multiplier);             
        button1.Text = "Price: " + price;                  
        textBox1.Text = "Item Bought";
        label4.Text = "Money: " + Convert.ToString(money);
        label1.Text = "Level: " + Convert.ToString(level);
        label3.Text = "Revenue: " + Convert.ToString(revenue);
    }


    private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        update();
    }
}
```

}

- Button1 is the level button, the player clicks this, subtracting
  money, and it levels up the gold mine one level at a time.
- Button2 is the collect button, the player clicks this which adds the
  revenue created from the gold mine.

However, to collect from Button2 the player must first click Button1 to level it up and I do not know how to solve this. The player should just be able to click on the collect button and add whatever the revenue is of the gold mine.

Please coud someone help, thank you - Maximus

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the following, it should make sense. You needed to initialize your variables and update using a thread. I used a timer since it was the easiest available resource.

```
public partial class Form1 : Form {

    public decimal level { get; set; }
    public decimal money { get; set; }
    public decimal revenue { get; set; }
    public decimal multiplier { get; set; }
    public decimal price { get; set; }

    private Timer Updater { get; set; }

    public Form1() {
        InitializeComponent();
        Updater = new Timer();
        Start();
    }
    void Start() {
        money = 10;
        multiplier = 1.10m;
        price = 5;

        label1.Text = "Level: " + money.ToString();
        label3.Text = "Revenue: " + revenue.ToString();
        button1.Text = "Price: " + price.ToString();
        label4.Text = "Money: " + money.ToString();

        Updater.Interval = 1000; //interval in milliseconds || this will tick every second
        Updater.Tick += Updater_Tick;
        Updater.Start();
    }

    private void Updater_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e) {
            money += revenue;

        label4.Text = "Money: " + money.ToString();


    }

    void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) {
        if (money >= price) {
            money -= price;
            price = ((price/100)*150m);
            button1.Text = "Price: " + price.ToString();
            level++;
            label1.Text = "Level: " + money.ToString();
            label3.Text = "Revenue: " + revenue.ToString();
            revenue = level*multiplier;


            textBox1.Text = "Item Bought";

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the help, this helped a lot :)

Answer (score 0):

I don't really understand your question. If user clicked Button2 then what will happen? If you want to force user to click Button1 first, you can set Button2 disabled by default and flip it to enable when Button1 clicked. Let me know how can I help.

Comment: The problem is button1 has to be pressed first to generate a value for revenue before button2 can be pressed which shouldn't be the case. Button2 sshould be able to be pressed at any time during the game to collect the revenue

Comment: @Maximus Then... *don't* disable the button?